# Why does np.nan cast my column into float when I run series.replace

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am cleaning up a file to get rid of the invalid phone numbers. I want to replace the invalid phones with a null value. When I replace the invalid values with a blank space it works fine. When I try to replace the invalid value with a np.nan so I can get null values python changes my column type form object to float.
'''

```
dfr=df['Mobile']

dfr.replace(0,np.nan,inplace=True,regex=False)

Out[]
7.864526e+09
3.055277e+09
7.868887e+09
7.035980e+09
NaN
9.543056e+09
Name: Mobile, Length: 167, dtype: float64
```

When 
I run

```
 dfr.replace(0,'',inplace=True,regex=False)
```

I get

```
7864525885
3055276596
7868887478
7035980427

Name: Mobile, Length: 167, dtype: object
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because `type(np.nan)` is `float`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the type of nan is a float.

Pandas actually uses the nan value from the numpy package (aka np.nan).

As mentioned in @PaulPanzer 's comment, if you try to check the type of np.nan with:

```
import numpy as np
print(type(np.nan))
```

You'll see that it is of type float.

Unfortunately there is no direct way around this, nan's are floats and will force the column into a "wider" data representation.

You could choose a different representation for nan like blank or "?" but then you'll have to manage it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with pandas 0.24+, you can do:

```
dfr.replace(0, np.nan,regex=False).astype('Int64')
```

And then you can have your data as integer.